# Adding a frame-ancestor header only for a specific site

Tags: configuration, site-configuration

Is it possible to add a `frame-ancestor` header only for a specific site in our multisite Sitecore environment? What I saw were articles suggesting to add the header in the `web.config` but that would add the header to all sites then, wouldn't it? I also saw articles that has a module for it but it's only for SXA (our site isn't built on SXA).

I can attempt to override the `XFrameOptionsHeaderModule` but that doesn't seem like good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding a `frame-ancestor` header only for a specific site in non SXA website you have to do customization, SXA have this feature. You can take reference from below link in non SXA website.

https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2018/07/27/Sitecore-SXA-Using-HTTP-Headers-to-Secure-Your-Site/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Pipelines, of course! I followed the implementation mentioned in the link you provided but modified it to read a configuration instead of it being configurable in the Content Editor.